# "<-" bindings in do notation

Tags: haskell, binding

I have a hard time grasping this. When writing in do notation, how are the following two lines different?

```
1. let x = expression
2. x <- expression
```

I can't see it. Sometimes one works, some times the other. But rarely both. "Learn you a haskell" says that `<-` binds the right side to the symbol on the left. But how is that different from simply defining `x` with `let`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `<-` statement will extract the value from a monad, and the `let` statement will not.

```
import Data.Typeable

readInt :: String -> IO Int
readInt s = do
  putStrLn $ "Enter value for " ++ s ++ ": "
  readLn

main = do
  x <- readInt "x"
  let y = readInt "y"
  putStrLn $ "x :: " ++ show (typeOf x)
  putStrLn $ "y :: " ++ show (typeOf y)
```

When run, the program will ask for the value of x, because the monadic action `readInt "x"` is executed by the `<-` statement.  It will not ask for the value of y, because `readInt "y"` is evaluated but the resulting monadic action is not executed.

```
Enter value for x: 
123
x :: Int
y :: IO Int
```

Since `x :: Int`, you can do normal `Int` things with it.

```
putStrLn $ "x = " ++ show x
putStrLn $ "x * 2 = " ++ show (x * 2)
```

Since `y :: IO Int`, you can't pretend that it's a regular `Int`.

```
putStrLn $ "y = " ++ show y -- ERROR
putStrLn $ "y * 2 = " ++ show (y * 2) -- ERROR
```

Answer (score 13):

In a `let` binding, the expression can have any type, and all you're doing is giving it a name (or pattern matching on its internal structure).

In the `<-` version, the expression must have type `m a`, where `m` is whatever monad the `do` block is in. So in the `IO` monad, for instance, bindings of this form must have some value of type `IO a` on the right-hand side. The `a` part (inside the monadic value) is what is bound to the pattern on the left-hand side. This lets you extract the "contents" of the monad within the limited scope of the `do` block.

The `do` notation is, as you may have read, just syntactic sugar over the monadic binding operators (`>>=` and `>>`). `x <- expression` de-sugars to `expression >>= \x ->` and `expression` (by itself, without the `<-`) de-sugars to `expression >>`. This just gives a more convenient syntax for defining long chains of monadic computations, which otherwise tend to build up a rather impressive mass of nested lambdas.

`let` bindings don't de-sugar at all, really. The only difference between `let` in a `do` block and `let` outside of a `do` block is that the `do` version doesn't require the `in` keyword to follow it; the names it binds are implicitly in scope for the rest of the `do` block.

Answer (score 9):

In the `let` form, the `expression` is a non-monadic value, while the right side of a `<-` is a monadic expression.  For example, you can only have an I/O operation (of type `IO t`) in the second kind of binding.  In detail, the two forms can be roughly translated as (where `==>` shows the translation):

```
do {let x = expression; rest} ==> let x = expression in do {rest}
```

and

```
do {x <- operation; rest} ==> operation >>= (\ x -> do {rest})
```

Answer (score 3):

`let` just assigns a name to, or pattern matches on arbitrary values.

For `<-`, let us first step away from the (not really) mysterious `IO` monad, but consider monads that have a notion of a "container", like a list or `Maybe`. Then `<-` does not more than "unpacking" the elements of that container. The opposite operation of "putting it back" is `return`. Consider this code:

```
add m1 m2 = do
   v1 <- m1
   v2 <- m2
   return (v1 + v2)
```

It "unpacks" the elements of two containers, add the values together, and wraps it again in the same monad. It works with lists, taking all possible combinations of elements:

```
main  = print $ add [1, 2, 3] [40, 50]
--[41,51,42,52,43,53]
```

In fact in case of lists you could write as well `add m1 m2 = [v1 + v2 | v1 <- m1, v2 <- m2]`. But our version works with `Maybe`s, too:

```
main  = print $ add (Just 3) (Just 12)
--Just 15
main  = print $ add (Just 3) Nothing
--Nothing
```

Now `IO` isn't that different at all. It's a container for a single value, but it's a "dangerous" impure value like a virus, that we must not touch directly. The `do`-Block is here our glass containment, and the `<-` are the built-in "gloves" to manipulate the things inside. With the `return` we deliver the full, intact container (and not just the dangerous content), when we are ready. By the way, the `add` function works with `IO` values (that we got from a file or the command line or a random generator...) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell reconciles side-effectful imperative programming with pure functional programming by representing imperative actions with types of form `IO a`: the type of an imperative action that produces a result of type `a`.

One of the consequences of this is that binding a variable to the value of an expression and binding it to the result of executing an action are two different things:

```
x <- action        -- execute action and bind x to the result; may cause effect
let x = expression -- bind x to the value of the expression; no side effects
```

So `getLine :: IO String` is an action, which means it must be used like this:

```
do line <- getLine -- side effect: read from stdin
   -- ...do stuff with line
```

Whereas `line1 ++ line2 :: String` is a pure expression, and must be used with `let`:

```
do line1 <- getLine            -- executes an action
   line2 <- getLine            -- executes an action
   let joined = line1 ++ line2 -- pure calculation; no action is executed
   return joined
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example showing you the difference.
Consider the two following simple expressions:

```
letExpression = 2
bindExpression = Just 2
```

The information you are trying to retrieve is the number `2`.
Here is how you do it:

```
let x = letExpression
x <- bindExpression
```

`let` directly puts the value `2` in `x`.
`<-` extracts the value `2` from the `Just` and puts it in `x`.

You can see with that example, why these two notations are not interchangeable:

`let x = bindExpression` would directly put the value `Just 2` in `x`.
`x <- letExpression` would not have anything to extract and put in `x`.