# re-write this example without do

Tags: haskell

I am reading that Haskell's [do notation is quite harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726659/should-do-notation-be-avoided-in-haskell).  Since I am still learning Haskell, I would like to not make bad habits.  I am learning a library called Reflex and is an example:

```
import Reflex.Dom

main = mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
  t <- textInput def
  dynText $ _textInput_value t
```

I am [reading](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful) that **do** notation has to do with the presence of monads such as `IO` and has to do with [`<-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932913/bindings-in-do-notation) and `$` operators.

How could I write these few lines without `do` ?

---

If you support `do`... could you explain it's use in Haskell and this example?

Comment: do notation is not harmful. in fact, do-notation has been expanded to applicatives, so we're encouraging its use even more.

Comment: Every single answer on the question you linked says that `do` notation is useful and should not be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`do`-notation is pure syntactic sugar. It translates into calls to `>>=` in a pretty simple way. Quoting [the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14):

> **Translation**: Do expressions satisfy these identities, which may be
>   used as a translation into the kernel, after eliminating empty `stmts`:
>
> ```
> do {e}    =   e
> do {e;stmts}  =   e >> do {stmts}
> do {p <- e; stmts}    =   let ok p = do {stmts}
>     ok _ = fail "..."
>   in e >>= ok
> do {let decls; stmts} =   let decls in do {stmts}
> ```

This means your example would look like this:

```
main = mainWidget $ el "div" $
  textInput def >>= $ \t ->
  dynText $ _textInput_value t
```

There's nothing harmful about `do`-notation. I don't know where you got that idea from! It's literally a different way of writing the same code.