# Haskell couldn't match 't0 ->t' with actual type '[Integer]'

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and after grasping some of the basics I decided to solve some easy problems in HackerRank. But I soon found myself stuck.

Problem 7 in Functional Problems is called "Array of N elements"

We are supposed to return any array of n elements for a given n. This would have fairly simple if n was an Int but it's read as `IO Int`. And I haven't really grasped the concept of monads. I hoogled for functions with type signature `IO Int -> Int` and found unsafePerform IO but it threw this:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> t’
              with actual type ‘[Integer]’
```

I dont't quite understand what types t0 and t are.

Any help is appreciated.

Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-array-of-n-elements/problem

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` is almost certainly the wrong answer. What solution did you attempt that gave you an `IO` where you weren't expecting it?

Comment: It's called "Array of N elements", Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-array-of-n-elements/problem

the haskell version atleast.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It's a programming challenge, which means you have to have attempted it with some code. What code did you use? Simply running the challenge with a blank function is not going to accomplish anything.

Comment: fn n = [1..(unsafePerformIO n)]

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your confusion now. Does my answer help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["<-" bindings in do notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932913/bindings-in-do-notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input to `fn` on that website *is* an `Int`. You're fundamentally misunderstanding the do-notation used here.

```
main = do
 n <- readLn :: IO Int
 print (fn(n))
```

The second line does not say `n` has type `IO Int`. It says `readLn` has type `IO Int`, which is then bound *inside* the `IO` monad to `n`. So `n` has type `Int`. Write your function as `fn :: Int -> [Int]` and you'll be just fine. No need to worry about `IO` in this challenge.

You can read more about do-notation [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation), but it probably won't make too much sense unless you've been through a Haskell tutorial that covers monads.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So the code would be same if it was just `n <- readLn` instead of `n<-readLn : IO Int`? Also I think I'll have to write `fn :: Int->[Int]`

Comment: Yes. The type signature is only there to remind you, the coder, what type you need to input. And you're correct about the output type; that was an oversight on my part.

Comment: I tried this: `fn :: Int -> [Int]   fn n = [1..n]` but it threw `Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> [Int]’
                  with actual type ‘[Int]’`
What does the type t0 mean? Any ambigous type?

Comment: Hey. I just figured it out. Apparently I had to remove the underlines before submitting. :)

Comment: Ah okay. Glad you figured it out!